# How can I add an Integer to a string and get a string answer?

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2010. 
I have tried several ways to try and add an integer to a string and then get the results as a string. Nothing I have tried seems to work. Below is the code I have at present time. Result is a label that I need to show the results after adding a 1 to the label result to get a new total. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
Result.Text = CStr(CInt(Result.Text + 1))
```

Comment: Your brackets are wrong, put the first closing bracket after `.Text`.  You're trying to add an int to a string right now rather than int to converted int.

Comment: You don't need to do everything in one line. First, convert the result.Text to an int.  Next, add 1 to the int.  Finally, convert the sum to a string.

Comment: Result.Text = (CInt(Result.Text) + 1).ToString

Comment: i tried this and still did not work. thank you for commenting. :)

Comment: If you're getting an error message telling you that an empty `String` can't be converted to an `Integer` then did it not occur to you that the issue may be trying to make that conversion in the first place?  You can only convert a `String` to an `Integer` if it makes sense to do so. An empty `String` doesn't magically become zero.  If the `String` might be empty then check whether it is first.  If you want to treat that as zero then do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add numbers with a string. You need to first convert the string into an integer. You can do this like this:

```
Dim resultInteger = CInt(Result.Text)
```

You can then add resultInteger to 1 and set Result.text to the answer like this:

```
Result.Text = (resultInteger + 1).ToString
```

It, however, is possible to do this all on one line:

```
Result.Text = (CInt(Result.Text) + 1).ToString
```

Note that if Result.Text does not contain a number then it will crash you application. You could use a try statement like this:

```
Try
Result.Text = (CInt(Result.Text) + 1).ToString
Catch ex As Exception
msgbox("Result does not contain an integer!")
End Try
```

Comment: Thank you so much... your code does work when result text starts with a 0.. The result text started with no number was my problem.

Comment: FYI, better to use `TryParse` than `Try-Catch`

Answer (score 0):

```
Result.Text = CStr(CInt(Result.Text) + 1)
```

Comment: i tried this and i get the message: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid. thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim intResult As Integer = 0
If Integer.TryParse(Result.Text, intResult) Then
   intResult += 1
   Result.Text = intResult.ToString()
End If
```